# Using graphviz nop from command line

Tags: cmd, graphviz

I need to make a lot of pdf (at worst some other, png for example) graphs from dot files. I've tried to do it from command line but faced a problem.
The problem is that I can't use layout engines like "dot" or "neato" cause nodes positions are forsed. In GVEdit I've used "nop" engine for this purpose. But then I tried `nop -Tpdf D0.dot -o D0.pdf` but I got this:

```
nop: option -T unrecognized - ignored
nop: option -d unrecognized - ignored
nop: option -f unrecognized - ignored
```

Other engines work perfectly.
Is there any way to make "nop" works?
Or any other ideas how to "put graph drawning on the conveyor".

Comment: "nop" documentation says than it can only be used to print .dot contents.
So the question is how to build forsed graph from command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use "dot" from command line with "-K" flag:

```
dot -Knop -Tpdf D1.dot -o D1.pdf
```